# passing stdout in subprocess to a module that wants to read from stdin (pysam)

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I am trying to write a pipeline in python and make proper use of subprocess and not invoke `shell=True`. One common task in bioinformatics is to align sequences with a program such as `bwa` and pass the sam-formatted results on to `samtools` to do downstream processing. The python package `pysam` helps me do all of the tasks `samtools` does but within python.

I would like to pass the results from a call to the aligner `bwa` to `pysam` without having to write to a file.

Pysam allows for you to open `Samfile` object with the input file being set to `"-"` and it will read from stdin. Similarly, `bwa` writes its results to stdout.

The way I have written it thus far is:

```
bwa_call = ["bwa", "mem", "-v", "1", "-t", str(cores), index, fwd, rev]
bwa = subprocess.Popen(bwa_call, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
samfile = pysam.Samfile("-", "r")
```

This seems to work, in that I don't see the stdout output from `bwa` but the problem is that `pysam` does not know when the file is finished and so just keeps waiting.

Is there a way in which I can pass the stdout from `bwa` directly to `pysam` without writing to a file?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://www.biostars.org/p/15298/

Comment: @shavenwarthog it does appear to be a duplicate, however the answers in that thread do not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466926/using-python-subprocess-to-redirect-stdout-to-stdin

Comment: Thanks @Parsimoni, that is similar to what I ended up doing. As far as I can tell this is only possible to solve with two scripts. Voting to close as duplicate.